# Adding a new page in MS Word using Qt

Tags: c++, qt, vba, ms-word, activex

I am using Qt 4.5 and using ActiveQt to generate MS Word documents. I am able to create a document based on the ActiveX commands of VBA for MS Word. But I am not able to create a new page at the desired position.

I tried

```
selection->dynamicCall("InsertBreak(const QString &)","wdPageBreak");
selection->dynamicCall("InsertParagraph(void)");
QAxObject *partTableParagraph = activeDocument->querySubObject("Paragraphs(1)");
partTableParagraph->setProperty("PageBreakBefore","True");
QAxObject *partTableRange = partTableParagraph->querySubObject("Range");
selection->dynamicCall("TypeText(const QString&)","second page contents");
```

but still I am not able to create a new page in the word document. Also the contents aren't visible for the second page. i.e `second page contents` isn't visible.

Any pointers regarding this are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you write this as a VBA macro first. Once you have got it working in VBA, you should be able to translate it straight to ActiveQt.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code. I'm able to insert a new page wherever I call this method:

```
void insertNewPage() {
    QAxObject* activeWindow = activeDocument->querySubObject( "ActiveWindow" );
    QAxObject* selection = activeWindow->querySubObject( "Selection" );
    selection->dynamicCall( "Collapse(int)", 0 );
    selection->dynamicCall( "InsertNewPage()" );
    selection->dynamicCall( "Collapse(int)", 0 );
}
```

For example, supposing you have a `write` method to write to your document:

```
write( "This is a test. " );
write("With no newline but with a page break");
writePageBreak();
write("But this has a newline at the beginning and the end\n");
```

You'll end with `This is a test. With no newline but with a page break` in one page and `But this has a newline at the beginning and the end` in the other.

I'm not checking for `NULL` pointers, though :)

As for why your second page is blank... I use this to write to Word:

```
QAxObject* selection = activeWindow->querySubObject( "Selection" );
selection->dynamicCall( "InsertAfter(const QString&)",text);
```

and up until now it has worked.